# how to create thiessen polygon around specific areas of interested area?

Tags: modelbuilder, voronoi-thiessen, iteration

I wish to create Thiessen polygon within all sub_basin of my interested area individually, meaning that to create Thiessen for every sub_basin one by one. I have to layer one is point layer and another is the shapefile of the study area which my sub_basins is located within it. I know it can be done using manually and also using ModelBuilder.

I prefer to use ModelBuilder.

[image: two layer including point layer and sub_basins]

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve in the end? Do the borders of the sub basins participate in or clip the Thiessen polygons?

Comment: You should attempt to get started on the model builder solution, and then when you're having trouble at a specific point, then ask for advice. As it stands, this is a very broad question.